# Broadcast Shapely Point on numpy array

Tags: python, shapely, numpy

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
def get_objs(all_objs, line, my_distance):
    """
    Gets all objs within my_distance of line.

    all_objs is a numpy array of shape (x, 4) denoting bounding-box coordinates.
    line is a LineString object with an arbitrary number of points. 
    """
    line_objs = []

    for o in all_objs:
        x_avg, y_avg = np.mean([o[0], o[1]]), np.mean([o[2], o[3]])

        p = Point(x_avg, y_avg)  # Point is a Shapely type

        if p.distance(line) <= my_distance:
            line_objs.append(o)

    return line_objs
```

My question is whether I can broadcast in this case, because this code is **really** slow on my data and I suspect a vectorised broadcast would help a ton. I have checked the numpy docs, but they don't make it clear that you can broadcast your inputs to a new type and then do something with that type.

Likewise the Shapely docs don't make it clear that you can apply the `.difference()` function in element-wise fashion so that you can compare to some geometric object. Perhaps I am being a bit optimistic. What I have in mind is something like:

```
x_avgs = (all_objs[:, 0] + all_objs[:, 1]) / 2
y_avgs = (all_objs[:, 2] + all_objs[:, 3]) / 2
xy_avgs = np.array((x_avgs, y_avgs)).transpose()

# element-wise initialisation and comparison, followed by
# masking for true-y elements.
line_objs = (Point(xy_avgs).distance(line) < my_distance).nonzero()

return line_objs
```

The above does not work, since `Point()`s don't accept arrays :(

---

#### After some (very statistically shaky) benchmarking, a quick consultation with `timeit`:

```
>>> setup = "import numpy as np; a = [(x, y, x, y) for x in range(100) for y in range(100)];"
>>> print(timeit.timeit("[(np.mean([o[0], o[1]]), np.mean([o[2], o[3]])) for o in a]", setup=setup, number=100))
30.91517815797124
>>> print(timeit.timeit("[((o[0] + o[1]) / 2, (o[2] + o[3]) / 2) for o in a]", setup=setup, number=100))
0.3588130779680796
```

... That's insane! That's nearly 2 orders of magnitude on a sample much smaller than mine. Perhaps vectorisation isn't necessary after all.

Comment: [The shapely docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#numpy-and-python-arrays) mention an array interface but it looks like you can only adapt 1x2 arrays to point objects, so I think you're out of luck.  Perhaps you could filter down to axis-aligned windows that could *potentially* be close enough using vectorized numpy operations before doing the more expensive test on that smaller subset of points or objects or whatever you have.

Comment: Are your real `o` objects just 4 coordinates or is that a simplified example?

Comment: @MarcPfister the input is a Numpy array of shape (x, 4), so yes, 4 coordinates (defining a bounding box per object).

Comment: It doesn't answer your question and still might not make a difference, but np.mean is ~20x slower than just adding the two values and dividing by two.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I never benchmarked, but that might help a huge deal. Will update with that attempt.

Comment: It's less efficient to calculate the distance to the line (which has to check the whole line) and then check it's under a threshold than to check each segment in your line and stop once it first meets your threshold. It might be faster do to this, even in pure Python.

Comment: There are probably other optimisations I can make elsewhere, but that's also a good suggestion. I just remembered this isn't C++, so there's no way the distance function could exit early as you suggest unless I wrote that myself.

Comment: For fun I did a pure Python test where it checks line segments and stops as soon as it hits a threshold, and Shapely was still 10X faster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shapely can give you this information so much faster, indeed. You can broadcast to a *`MultiPoint()`* object, which is sequence of `Point()` objects, in a single step.

Next, you may want to create a [*buffer*](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) for the line. A buffer around a line is the polygon representing the area in which all points are within a given distance. Because you want to return the rows from `all_objs` that fall within the boundaries, you need to test individual points from the multipoint object (otherwise a simple intersection would have done, e.g. `multipoint & line.buffer(distance)`). Iterating over a multipoint gives you individual `Point()` instances, but much faster than if you created separate `Point()` objects for each row.

First, just use [`ndarray.sum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) as the base of your averages, then use `numpy.stack()` to combine the averages into a single array (shape: `(..., 2)`). Then use [`asMultiPoint()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#numpy-and-python-arrays) to create a Shapely `MultiPoint()` object from the array:

```
from shapely.geometry import asMultiPoint

x_avgs = all_objs[:, :2].sum(axis=1) / 2
y_avgs = all_objs[:, 1:3].sum(axis=1) / 2
xy_avgs = np.stack((x_avgs, y_avgs), axis=1)

points = asMultiPoint(xy_avgs)
```

Next, you want to create your line buffer, and from that buffer create a [*prepared object*](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations) as that provides the fastest method to test point containment:

```
from shapely.prepared import prep
prepped_buffer = prep(line.buffer(distance))
```

`prepped_buffer` has a `.contains()` method that returns `True` if a given point falls within its boundaries.

Finally, use the `prepped_buffer` to determine what rows represent a point that's within the buffer boundary. I'd use [`numpy.compress()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress), and `map()` to avoid switching between Python and C constantly:

```
# boolean array indicating what points were contained within distance from the line
contained = np.fromiter(map(prepped_buffer.contains, points), np.bool)
# take all rows from all_objs that are within distance from line
result = np.compress(contained, all_objs, axis=0)
```

I'm feeding the `map()` result into `np.compress()` via `np.fromiter()` as that's a lot faster than using `list()`; the latter has to create individual Python `bool` references, while `np.fromiter()` creates a much more compact object with single bits for the boolean values (8 to a byte).

This takes abo ut 80ms on 10.000 values. I ran a setup in a separate IPython cell, creating a function for the above process:

```
# setup
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString
a = np.array([(x, y, x, y) for x in range(100) for y in range(100)])
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
distance = 0.5

def select_by_linebuffer(a, line, distance):
    x_avgs = a[:, :2].sum(axis=1) / 2
    y_avgs = a[:, 1:3].sum(axis=1) / 2
    xy_avgs = asMultiPoint(np.stack((x_avgs, y_avgs), axis=1))
    prepped_buffer = prep(line.buffer(distance))
    return np.compress(
        np.fromiter(map(prepped_buffer.contains, points), dtype=np.bool),
        a,
        axis=0
    )
```

then used the `%timeit` IPython magic command to time the whole operation:

```
%timeit select_by_linebuffer(a, line, distance)
# 82.9 ms ± 4.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comparing this to your `get_objs()` function:

```
%timeit get_objs(a, line, distance)
# 534 ms ± 30.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So ~80ms vs over 500ms, a win by a factor of 6 or 7. As you increase the size of the input, this only gets (much) worse, as the vectorised method has very little overhead:

```
# 250k rows
a = np.array([(x, y, x, y) for x in range(500) for y in range(500)])
%timeit select_by_linebuffer(a, line, distance)
# 86.9 ms ± 1.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit get_objs(a, line, distance)
12.5 s ± 121 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So for 250.000 rows, the vectorised method took a few milliseconds more time, while the Python loop approach took 12.5 seconds (!).

I tried to run the test on 1 million rows and my MacBook Pro 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 laptop took such a long time to run `get_objs()` that after 5 minutes I aborted the run, while the vectorized version managed to run the job in 121 milliseconds.

The difference is that with `np.compress()` you get a single numpy array, while your `get_objs()` function built up a Python list of separate arrays. I'd argue that that's much better.

Answer (score 1):

To add a update to Martijn Pieters answer. On shapely 1.8.0, the version I've tested the method on, using asMultiPoint will raise a error. However, simply switching to MultiPoint works. This is in line with the deprecation warning in the MultiPointAdapter class:

```
"The proxy geometries (through the 'asShape()', 'asMultiPoint()' "
        "or 'MultiPointAdapter()' constructors) are deprecated and will be "
        "removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the 'shape()' function or the "
        "standard 'MultiPoint()' constructor instead.",
```